# What is the proper way to rotate log files which are mapped from a host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logrotate

As we know, we can map files from host machine to docker container.
We also know that there are some OS tools, which can help us to rotate log files.

Now I use `docker-compose` to run a container with some file mapping. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

x-volumes-common: &volumes_common
  - "./openfire_https.log:/openfire_https.log:rw"
  - "./openfire_tcp.log:/openfire_tcp.log:rw"

services:
  envoy:
    image: xxx/yyy
    volumes: *volumes_common
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
```

As you see, two log files are mapping from the host machine to the docker container.
I have to try to rotate the two log files periodically since this container provides some web services and write logs into the two files.

I’m not sure if it is possible or is a proper way to rotate the two files from the host machine (Ubuntu16.04) with the tool `logrotate` as the two files are mapped from the host machine, I don’t know if I rotate them from the host machine immediately, what would happen, will it work as I expected? Or will it lose some log data?